# How do I create a Validation feature for User Profiles in MySites (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: user-profile, sharepoint-server, user

I have a request for users to be prompted on their MySites page if one of their User Profile property has not be completed.

I came across a similar question -[Displaying a User Profile Property](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40758/displaying-a-user-profile-property)

In my case I need to be able to let the user know which property is missing so they can edit their profile and fill out the missing record/information.

This prompt will appear unti they have completed the property with the required information