# does user profile service application or synchronisation pull in AD details like password and expiry?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-server, active-directory, password

We use user profile service application for one way AD sync . we can pull in data like the name email phones etc.

I would like to know if there was any way in which we could retrieve the password expiry date value of the user profile.

Is it possible using USPA or the hidden share point simple.aspx list?

Answer (score 1):

you can map password expire property( i believe accountExpires is) in SharePoint user profile mapping. Then you can display where ever you want
You can use the power shell to do this...check the 2nd part of this below blog.

http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2011/02/create-custom-ad-attribute-and-map-it.html

To display in profile or embed in the Master page.check below solutions.

[Displaying a User Profile Property](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40758/displaying-a-user-profile-property)